# How to do a VHDL "typedef"

Tags: typedef, vhdl

I want to "create" a type "my_type", which is a std_logic_vector(...), like this C/VHDL fake code:
typedef std_logic_vector(CONSTANT downto 0) my_type.

"type" does not allow you to do it with std_logic_vector(...), only with array, and "alias" uses only valid types, you can't create a type with it.

So how to do it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need subtype

```
subtype foo is std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, "subtype" worked, with a little change:
subtype foo **is** std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);